# Regex to allow number with leading special character

Tags: regex

Here's what I've got so far:
`^([<>0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?)?$`

I need to allow the following:

```
1234.1234
.11
0.11
>11
<11
< 11
```

I need the following to fail:

```
12345.12345
12345
.12345
12>3
123<
>>123
<<123
```

I can't figure out the `>` and `<` parts to allow only once and only leading the string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?:[<>] ?)?(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?|\.[0-9]{1,4})$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS2yZ7/1)

It ensures that there is at least one digit with this alternation:
`[0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})? | \.[0-9]{1,4}`
and makes the space optional only if there is a `<` or a `>` at the start with:
`^(?:[<>] ?)?`

I assumed that capture groups are not needed so I used non-capturing groups instead: `(?:...)`

Note that to figure a literal dot you need to escape it: `\.`

Answer (score 0):

I think `^[<>]?\s?(\d{,4})?\.?(\d{1,4})?$` should do it.

You can use http://regexpal.com to help you verify.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your answer